# How to merge multiple feature file in mock server using karate?

Tags: karate

I am using runner class as follows:
https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/examples/consumer-driven-contracts/payment-producer/src/test/java/payment/producer/mock/PaymentContractAgainstMockTest.java

Now I have multiple mock feature files which I want to use in single runner. I understand from 0.9.6 release notes that this is available but I am not sure on what changes I have to do to this file?
https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/examples/consumer-driven-contracts/payment-producer/src/test/java/payment/producer/mock/PaymentContractAgainstMockTest.java

Need help with the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FeatureServer.start(files, 0, false, null)` can take a `List<File>` as the first argument.